# Can't connect to a Oracle db instance via SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sql-developer

When I set the connecting information on the GUI in SQLDeveloper I get the following error (everytime!)

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Connection information:

> user: hr
>
> pass: hr
>
> Conn. type: basic / Role: default
>
> hostname: localhost
>
> port: 1521
>
> SID: xe

I couldn't connect with the sys user either.

Previously I successfully unlocked the HR user through SQLPLUS command line

(as described [here:](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm?cid=4205&ssid=4289911489000)

and set the port=localhost in the tnsnames.ora and listener.ora, the OracleXETNSListener service is up and running as well as the OracleServiceXE)

Sadly I'm still getting this error message...

I'm on a laptop (with wireless wifi connection only), under Windows 7.
What might be the problem?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime I figured it out myself.

The connection couldn't be established from SQL Developer because I was logged into my company's VPN and so "localhost" was resolved somehow as an IPV6 address.

When I closed the VPN connection and tried to connect with the same connection information it worked, localhost was resolved as normal IPV4 address then.